# Пирамида с обратным порядком строк

Tags: c, циклы

Надо сделать пирамиду с обратным порядком строк, вида

```
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

Пока получается только вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size;

    scanf("%d", &size);
    for ( int row = 1; row <= size; row++ ) {
        for ( int col = 1; col < row; col++ ) {
            printf("%d ", col);
        }

        printf("%d\n", row);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Натолкните на правильную мысль =)

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под словом «пирамида»?

Comment: Что-то такого вида:
1 2 3
1 2
1
Сейчас оно выглядит вот так:
1
1 2
1 2 3

Comment: А можно более формальное определение? А то я на одном примере не разобрался.

Comment: Нужно что бы пирамида сверху была широкой и сужалась вниз. А сейчас у меня, допустим, при размере 3, 1 символ сверху, 2 во втором ряду, 3 в третьем. Нужно вверх ногами :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы вам не нумеровать строки в обратном порядке?

```
for ( int row = size; row >= 1; row-- )
```